# Image Distortion with Lock Bits

Tags: c#, image, image-processing, edge-detection

I'm having a problem with writing to files using lock bits. I'm working on an edge detection software which has a strange distortion effect with most images. I've tried to isolate the problem, and it seems very random. It is not associated with format, but rather the only images that seem to work are pictures made for desktop wallpapers, and I don't really know why. I only switched to writing to files using lockbits recently, so I am sure the problem is with that (there were no problems when I was reading with lockbits and writing with set pixel). Here's a screenshot of the effect:

[image: Screenshot]

As you can see, the edge detection works, but the image is distorted horizontally, making the image into a parallelogram.

Here's a code snippet of the method that handles all this (in C#):

```
private void analyze()
{
    //When the analyze button is pressed
    percentageInt = float.Parse(textBox1.Text);
    float scale = 1;

    if (comboBox1.SelectedItem == "Auto")
    {
        scale = pic.Width / pictureBox1.Width;
    }
    else if (comboBox1.SelectedItem == "1/2")
    {
        scale = 2;
    }
    else if (comboBox1.SelectedItem == "1/4")
    {
        scale = 4;
    }
    else if (comboBox1.SelectedItem == "Original")
    {
        scale = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        scale = pic.Width / pictureBox1.Width;
    }

    int tempWidth = 1;
    int tempHeight = 1;
    if (scale >= 1)
    {
        tempWidth = (int)Math.Floor(pic.Width / scale);
        tempHeight = (int)Math.Floor(pic.Height / scale);
    }
    else
    {
        tempWidth = pic.Width;
        tempHeight = pic.Height;
    }

    width = pic.Width;
    height = pic.Height;
    edgeData = new Boolean[pic.Width, pic.Height];

    img = (Bitmap)resizeImage(pic, new Size(tempWidth, tempHeight));
    pic2 = new Bitmap(tempWidth, tempHeight);
    Bitmap img2 = (Bitmap)pic2;
    Color[] pixels = null;

    BitmapData data = img.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, img.Width, img.Height),
            ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

    int size = Math.Abs(data.Stride) * img.Height;
    Byte[] bytes = new byte[size];

    int scaledPercent = (int)(Math.Round(percentageInt * 255));
    Debug.WriteLine("percent " + scaledPercent);
    unsafe
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Woah there, unsafe stuff");
        byte* prevLine = (byte*)data.Scan0;
        byte* currLine = prevLine + data.Stride;
        byte* nextLine = currLine + data.Stride;

        for (int y = 1; y < img.Height - 1; y++)
        {
            byte* pp = prevLine + 3;
            byte* cp = currLine + 3;
            byte* np = nextLine + 3;
            for (int x = 1; x < img.Width - 1; x++)
            {
                if (IsEdgeOptimized(pp, cp, np, scaledPercent))
                {
                    edgeData[x, y] = true;
                    //Debug.WriteLine("x " + x + "y " + y);

                    //img2.SetPixel(x, y, Color.Black);
                    //bytes[(y * img.Width + x) * 3 + 2] = 255;
                }
                else
                {
                    bytes[(y * img.Width + x) * 3] = 255;
                    bytes[(y * img.Width + x) * 3 + 1] = 255;
                    bytes[(y * img.Width + x) * 3 + 2] = 255;
                    //img2.SetPixel(x, y, Color.White);
                }
                pp += 3; cp += 3; np += 3;
            }
            prevLine = currLine;
            currLine = nextLine;
            nextLine += data.Stride;
        }
    }
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(bytes, 0, data.Scan0, size);
    img.UnlockBits(data);
    pictureBox2.Image = img;
} // end analyze
```

So what is causing the problem, and how can I fix it? If you need more details, feel free to comment.

Comment: it looks like the image has an alpha channel, so you have 32 bits per pixel and not 24

Comment: I thought it was that, but I've encountered this problem with jpg images, which can't support transparency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're initializing your bytes buffer with stride x height bytes:

```
int size = Math.Abs(data.Stride) * img.Height;
Byte[] bytes = new byte[size];
```

But then using the width (instead of stride) when you write to it:

```
bytes[(y * img.Width + x) * 3] = 255;
```

Comment: Replacing img.Width with data.Stride causes an indexOutOfBounds exception, any idea why?

Comment: You're multiplying the entire offset with 3, instead of just the x. Try "bytes[y * data.Stride + x * 3] = 255;".

Comment: Remember that the stride is bytes/row, not pixels!